# Modal window displays very briefly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal window that loads and disappears almost instantly,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">School Management Portal</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade in modal-dialog modal-content" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

Why does it close so quickly after `modal('show')`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

should be

```
$('#basicModal').modal('show');
```

Since that is the `id` of your modal `div`.

*Alternatively* (but for the same reason), this

```
<div class="modal fade in modal-dialog modal-content" id="basicModal"
```

could be

```
<div class="modal fade in modal-dialog modal-content" id="myModal"
```

I believe you're only seeing it on load, and it disappears because it isn't visible yet. Basically, your `show()` doesn't currently function.